# Cannot use petsc with cmake

Tags: cmake, petsc

I was trying to build a project that uses PETSc. To do so, I downloaded the cmake modules from https://github.com/jedbrown/cmake-modules . When I tried to build the project, I got the following error messages:

```
(...)

-- petsc_lib_dir /cygdrive/d/Git-Projects/build_libs/INSTALL/petsc-3.7.5/lib
-- Recognized PETSc install with single library for all packages
-- Performing Test MULTIPASS_TEST_1_petsc_works_minimal
-- Performing Test MULTIPASS_TEST_1_petsc_works_minimal - Failed
-- Performing Test MULTIPASS_TEST_2_petsc_works_allincludes
-- Performing Test MULTIPASS_TEST_2_petsc_works_allincludes - Failed
-- Performing Test MULTIPASS_TEST_3_petsc_works_alllibraries
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
PETSC_LIBRARY_SINGLE
    linked by target "cmTC_bb78d" in directory /cygdrive/d/Git-Projects/EFVLib_dev/EFVLib/_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Performing Test MULTIPASS_TEST_3_petsc_works_alllibraries - Failed
-- Performing Test MULTIPASS_TEST_4_petsc_works_all
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
PETSC_LIBRARY_SINGLE
    linked by target "cmTC_9aa2b" in directory /cygdrive/d/Git-Projects/EFVLib_dev/EFVLib/_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
PETSC_LIBRARY_SINGLE (ADVANCED)
```

I've downloaded openMPI (cygwin packages) and built Petsc using:

"--prefix="where_petsc_will_be_installed" --with-clanguage=C --with-mpi --with-cc=mpicc --with-cxx=0 --with-fc=0 --download-f2cblaslapack --with-debugging=yes"

and the paths were exported using:

```
export PETSC_DIR="where_petsc_is_installed"
export PETSC_ARCH=""
export PATH=${PATH}:${PETSC_DIR}/lib:${PETSC_DIR}/bin
```

Why did I get these errors and how to solve them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use petsc with cmake in cygwin, it must be built using "--with-shared-libraries=0", you must use static libs.